# Replace portions of a string in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

As a CAD Manager for a small firm, I often have to set up Project folders with Client specific resource files for each new project. It can be a tedious process with files and folders in various locations.

I created a batch file relying heavily on robocopy and using a bunch of simple code that I learned searching the internet to set the folder and file names. It prompts me, the user, for project information, then creates a set of standard files and folders based on that input.

Here is the part of my code that I need help with. It may not be the best method but it works for my purposes mostly. I'm trying to simplify it/ rewrite it to a more "correct" method. I had trouble getting the `&` symbol replacement to work where the `&` seems to break the string placed after it, but I managed to use a workaround by adding quotes " " around the first set string, then removing them at the end.

```bash
@echo off
echo Enter a brief Project description:
set /p projdesc=
echo.
REM # replace characters in description
set descname="%projdesc%"
set descname=%descname:the =%
set descname=%descname:to =_%
set descname=%descname: over =_%
set descname=%descname: at =_%
set descname=%descname: =%
set descname=%descname:&=-%
set descname=%descname:.=%
set descname=%descname:"=%
echo %descname%
pause
```

So if I enter `Rt.71 Bridge over Shark River` the output is `Rt71Bridge_SharkRiver`.
But if I enter `Bridges & Tunnels` I was getting an error message and the output was only `Bridges`. With the fix it outputs `Bridges-Tunnels`.

I'm using two different variables - `projdesc` and `descname` - because I use the original description elsewhere in the batch file and the modified string as part of a folder name in other parts of my batch file.

I understand there are flaws in the text replacement in case of words ending in `the`  or `to` . So how can I fix that, too?

*update*

Thanks to your help I was able to correct my syntax that solved the "&" problem. Here is the updated code:

```bash
@echo off
echo Enter a brief Project description:
set /p projdesc=
echo.
REM # replace characters in description
set "descname=%projdesc%"
set "descname=%descname:the =%"
set "descname=%descname:to =_%"
set "descname=%descname: over =_%"
set "descname=%descname: at =_%"
set "descname=%descname: =%"
set "descname=%descname:&=-%"
set "descname=%descname:.=%"
echo %descname%
pause
```

I'm sure there has to be a better way to do this?

Comment: The answer is simple, and not what you have used in your answer. The proper syntax for the `set` command is ```set "VariableName=StringValue"```. In this scenario, the outer doublequotes are not included within the variable name or its string value.

Comment: What happens if the string `bathe` or `breathe` exist? What about `into`, `photo`, `ghetto`, `manifesto` or `mosquito`?

Comment: Excellent points, and definitely concerns I had when originally figuring out how to best write it... which I guess is why I'm asking here. But it basically works, just not for every scenario. I clarified the post and deleted my answer that wasn't really an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Compo Thanks, that was a simple fix. I corrected my syntax to `set "descname=%projdesc%"` and so on, as per your comment and that solved the "&" problem.

Comment: BTW, you could remove `set "descname=%projdesc%"` completely and start with `set "descname=%projdesc:the =%"`, or if you aren't using the initial input again, just use `set "projdesc=%projdesc:the =%"` etc. (you don't need to have two variables when only one is used).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using following command lines in the batch file for a fail-safe version:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
:UserPrompt
set ProjDesc=
set /P "ProjDesc=Enter a brief project description: " || goto UserPrompt
rem Remove all douible quotes from project description.
set "ProjDesc=%ProjDesc:"=%"
if not defined ProjDesc goto UserPrompt
rem Remove or replace words and characters in description.
set "ProjDesc=%ProjDesc: the =%"
if not defined ProjDesc goto UserPrompt
set "ProjDesc=%ProjDesc:.=%"
if not defined ProjDesc goto UserPrompt
set "ProjDesc=%ProjDesc: at =_%"
set "ProjDesc=%ProjDesc: to =_%"
set "ProjDesc=%ProjDesc: over =_%"
set "ProjDesc=%ProjDesc:&=-%"
set "ProjDesc=%ProjDesc: =%"
if not defined ProjDesc goto UserPrompt
echo(
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Project description is: !ProjDesc!
endlocal
echo(
pause
endlocal
```

Please read first: [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) It explains `|| goto UserPrompt` and why there is used first `set "ProjDesc=%ProjDesc:"=%"` for removal of all `"` before processing further the user input string.

It is always possible that the string right to the equal sign after the variable name becomes an empty string on using a string substitution on which all occurrences of a string are removed because of no string right to the second equal sign. That means an execution of `set "ProjDesc="` causing a deletion of the environment variable `ProjDesc`. The environment variable is not defined anymore for that reason on reaching the next command line.

See also: [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) It explains in full details why `set "variable=value"` is the best syntax for processing environment variables in a batch file processed by the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe`.

DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) explains the reason for using `echo(` or `echo/` for the output of an empty line. `echo.` causes in best case two easy to avoid file system accesses before the empty line is output and in worst case an execution of something different than the output of an empty line.

The output of the final project description should be done with enabled [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) on not being enclosed in `"` for avoiding the execution of commands not stored in the batch file caused by the user input string which still could contain characters with special meaning for `cmd.exe` like `|`.